# Create absolute path in cpio archive

Tags: cpio, pax

I build some archive for linux kernel it need an archive file with absolute path.
File are under folder /data/
when I pack normally it keeps file path like this

```
bin/ln
bin/ls
etc
```

the command I used is like this

```
cd /data
find|cpio -o -H newc -F ../data.cpio
```

but I want cpio to keep file with root path like this

```
/bin/ln
/bin/ls
/etc
```

I found I shuold use pax but  I dont know how to write regex for path replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as long as no filename contain the '>' characters:

```
pax -w -x sv4cpio -s '>^\.>>' . >../data.cpio
```

The `-x sv4cpio` should satisfy the requirement for using `-H newc` (SVR4 format).

Comment: thanx alot it saved my time, can you explain what is the meaning of ^ in your regex

Comment: ^ tells regex to match the start of the string. (And $ tells regex to match the end of the string).

Comment: Please note that `-x sv4cpio` is non-portable and applies only to one specific `pax` implementation that is not `pax` compliant since it does not support `-x pax`. This specific `pax` implementation you have in mind therefore is still at a development state from 1992.